# Error opening model as mat file in python?

Tags: python, matlab, upload

I am trying to open a model.mat file in python  as follow.

But I am getting an error: "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'reactions'"

The file supposed to be a full model and I was expecting to inspect the number of reactions etc.

```
import scipy.io as sio

model= sio.loadmat("C:/Users/mydirectory/myfile.mat")

print(len(model.reactions))
print(len(model.metabolites))
print(len(model.genes))
```

Answer (score 0):

Method which you use returns dict (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html )
Only way to access dict values is by:

```
model["reactions"]
```

If you really need to use get values as you described you can create Namespace for that dict e.g.:

```
from argparse import Namespace
ns = Namespace(**model)
```

and now ns.reactions will work